# How to capture the essence of an object-oriented API "ideally"?

Tags: algorithm, api, oop, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm confused as to how *best* to organize the fields/properties of an object. Specifically, the graphic sprite. These are some of the ways you can create the object:

```
{
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  marginTop: 2,
  marginRight: 3,
  marginBottom: 4,
  marginLeft: 5,
  alpha: 0.5,
  red: 200,
  blue: 200,
  green: 200
  // ...
}
```

Or a million ways in between. Or this for example:

```
{
  size: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10
  },
  margin: {
    top: 2,
    right: 3,
    bottom: 4,
    left: 5
  },
  color: {
    red: 200,
    blue: 200,
    green: 200,
    alpha: 0.5
  }
}
```

One reason you might want to have these nested objects vs. the flat structure, is for type-checking. You would have clear objects with specific types which could be used elsewhere. But the reason for the flat structure is potentially performance in accessing the properties. But, you loose some of the conceptual relations which the nested object provides. So I am confused.

I am confused because in HTML you are essentially at this strucure:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  style: {
    margin: {
      top: 2,
      right: 3,
      bottom: 4,
      left: 5
    },
    color: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5)'
  }
}
```

Or perhaps the width and height are moved into the style object. But we just showed you can have a flat list of properties in the first example. And why the need for the nested `style` object. Why is "margin" (a pixel value for sizing) separated into `style` while width/height are delegated to the element? I'm not actually wondering why HTML did it this way, or if there are other ways of viewing it. I am just using this as an example to demonstrate that there are potentially many various ways of doing the same thing. Having nested or flat objects in various configurations and combinations.

I could imagine having a div be like this too:

```
{
  vector: [10, 10],
  marginVector: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  colorVector: [200, 200, 200, 0.5]
}
```

Needless to say, there's unlimited ways of organizing the code, with tradeoffs in every direction.

But what I want to know is if there is some notion of an "ideal representation" of an object. Is one way better than the other in the end? Specifically in terms of being generic.

A related example is how list iteration works. If you worry about implementation details of lists, like if it is using pointers vs. a dynamic language, or if you have complex data structure implementations of lists, etc., then you have to write a custom implementation of each list iteration algorithm.

```
iterateThisListType
iterateThatListType
...
```

This creates the problem of that you now don't have a "generic list iteration algorithm", like those you learn in school. Each list iteration algorithm can be totally different depending on architecture-specific/etc. implementation details.

This problem can be solved by using the concept of "iterators". Passing an iterator to the list algorithm allows you to have a very simple, **single** list iteration algorithm.

```
for (item in iterator) {
  ...
}
```

Not something that doesn't resemble list iteration at all (just making this up):

```
let something = *another;
while (true) {
  if (something->else > 10) {
    complicated....
  } else {
    complicated...
  }
}
```

That doesn't capture the "essence" of list iteration like the iterator does.

In the same light, I am wondering how do we capture the "essence" of a DOM node? It makes total sense on some level to group everything under `style`, or to make `color` all one object, etc. But at the same time, it also makes sense to have a top-level `red` and `blue`, etc. rather than nesting it in an object. So how can we do similar to the list-iteration example and capture the *essence* of the DOM node? (Or any other relatively complex structure)

It only gets more complicated when you start to think more in terms of *graphics* and *effects*. In graphics, like in sound production, you have all kinds of "effects" that are applied to the main object, our sprite in the graphics example. Some effects are "drop shadow", "blur", "reflection", "old film", and [many others](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-filters/tree/master/filters). Often times (in the graphics case) the effects are simply modifying existing lower-level properties on the object. So like blur might just modify the `pixels` attribute (where each pixel has a `color` of some sort). (Just making this up). Effects (or you could call them "filters"), could also be like regular properties it seems. Grayscale, for example, could be a top-level boolean:

```
{
  grayscale: true
}
```

Or it could be an effect:

```
{
  effects: [
    { type: 'grayscale' }
  ]
}
```

Well if you are doing this, then why not just make "width" and "height" into effects too! I mean, they are effects of the object as well, "giving them a size".

```
{
  effects: [
    { type: 'grayscale' },
    { type: 'width', value: 10 },
    { type: 'height', value: 10 }
  ]
}
```

Well now we are seeing that effects could then just be thought of as attributes in this simple case, and we can go back to the flat top-level attribute example. But some other effects seem to be layers on top of lower-level "effects/attributes", sort of forming a graph of processing on some "fundamental" attributes. So I don't know! I am wondering, is there an "ideal" approach to this? Is there a way to "capture the essence" of the graphics sprite? To make it so that every algorithm that used it could be written in one way (like the iterator)? So in one case we don't have top-level flat attributes, and another nested, and another effects, etc. Which one is right? How do we arrive at the ideal?

That was just for demonstration.

My question is about the DOM node. Not specifically the DOM node API and how it works or why it is like that, but about the philosophy behind it. How can we capture the essence of the DOM node attributes in this way?

Another quick example... It seems you could nest things pretty deeply if you wanted to.

```
{
  type: 'animal',
  body: {
    organs: {
      skin: {
        mesh3d: {
          texture: {
            color: '#ff0000'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rather than just doing:

```
{
  type: 'animal',
  color: '#ff0000'
}
```

You might have a really complicated mesh which is has a color on the texture. But then you want to just think about it as "the animal has a color". So I am confused on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your point, I would say that related properties may be grouped into their own object types because that is useful to give structure to the data. It is easier to mentally cope with structured data versus long linear lists of attributes. And probably the data has itself some structure. Linear structures like a list of integers are very simple and objects from real world are more complex than that although lists are actually quite common.

The technique will just reflect that reality in a proper data structure.

You refer the "DOM" node. While probably you should refer the "DOM tree".

A tree is a good non-linear data structure both to store data in nodes, to annotate the nodes with metadata, and it is efficient for search, walk and edit.

If you don't like to think in tree terms, maybe you like lists of lists, which is essentially the same thing.

I think that to capture the essence you have to think what abstractions you use when thinking, or writing about the problem and then reflect that in the fields of your data representations.

HTML separates document structure from presentation style which should use CSS. That justifies the kind of separations between  you are describing.

Why the DOM structure is like the DOM structure, is probably because browsers have to parse it, in that regard, that should be tight related to (abstract) syntax trees in compilers.

I suspect you know all this and somehow it didn't make the click, or you are talking about something at a deeper level and I didn't get it.